# Parameter visibility based on chosen value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx

I'd like to make parameteres visible (or accesible)  based on previously choosen value.
Eg. user is chosen type of 'time' in the first parameter: quarter = TRUE and year = FALSE then according to the value from first parameter, user will see list of quarters or list of years. 
Where and how to place that condition? I thought of adding an expresion  : =Iif(Parameters!Time.Value=TRUE,FALSE,TRUE) to the default values of 'quarter' parameter but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "make parameteres visible (or accesible)"? Should the chosen parameter values be visible in the report display? Should they be part of the MDX result set? In the latter case, there could probably be a separate column for each parameter returning the selected value, but I doubt it makes much sense to return many rows which have the same value in each parameter column.

Comment: The user will see the list with the values of second parameter only if he previusly chose value in the firs paramter - this is what I mean 'make parameter visible'. He doesnt see second parametry by default.Yes, it will be part of result and I want to display it on report: items by years or items by quarter.

Comment: Ok, as I understand your question, you want to have cascading parameters in the report as described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169.aspx. How you would put the parameters into an MDX query depends on the structure of the hierarchies that you are accessing. Without knowing this structure, an answer would have to guess from some typical structures. I would therefore suggest that you edit your query and state the structure of your time hierarchy and the specific parameters you want to use on it.